# Can not start application pool error: Cannot write configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: iis-7, windows-clustering

I have 2 nodes configured in clustered environment, Both the nodes are running IIS with shared configuration stored in storage disk accessible to both the nodes. But when My cluster is connected to node 2, my application pool for an application is not starting. Error is
[Error_applicationhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm6uo.jpg)

Now when I am trying to access IIS_SHARED_FOLDER from Node 1 I am seeing the applicationhost.config file, but when I am trying to access it from node 2, I am not seeing applicationhost.config file in shared folder.
Permissions seems to be identical in both the nodes.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Rohit

Comment: You would have to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to involve Microsoft support team. You might review if you missed any specific step in https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/970759/configure-iis-world-wide-web-publishing-service-in-failover-cluster but without touching your environment, nobody can help much.

Comment: It was working fine yesterday, I haven't changed much, just added 1 service to the clustered generic service and after cluster fail-over this issue occurred.